# I cannot re-purchase in app purchase - consumables

Tags: xcode, transactions, in-app-purchase, payment

I am doing a system "in app purchase - consumables" . At the first time, I can purchase normally but when I tried to buy in the next time, it did not work. So I changed a test user, it could purchase only the first time as well. It showed “SK payment transaction state failed”, how should I fix?

```
- (void)buyProduct:(int)myNumber{
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:[appDelegate.ArrayProductName objectAtIndex:myNumber]];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled){
                    NSLog(@"An error encounterd : %@",transaction.error.code);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction { 
    [self verifyReceipt:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

}

- (BOOL)verifyReceipt:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSString* jsonObjectString =  [self encode:(uint8_t *)transaction.transactionReceipt.bytes length:transaction.transactionReceipt.length];    
    NSString* completeString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"myurl?receipt=%@", jsonObjectString];
    NSURL* urlForValidation = [NSURL URLWithString: completeString];
    NSMutableURLRequest* validationRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: urlForValidation];
   [validationRequest setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
    NSData * responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:validationRequest  returningResponse: nil  error: nil];
    NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: responseData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"return data : %@",responseString);
    int success = [responseString intValue];
    return (success == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried to buy. system alert "You've already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded. Tap OK to Download it now"

Do we need to send the data to server of Apple before for complete system to re-purchase by using PHP as the links?

http://www.phpriot.com/articles/verifying-app-store-receipts-php-curl

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012484